# PeopleSoft prompt table adding eff_status criteria

Tags: view, prompt, peoplesoft

I am using a custom prompt table (PS_AVZ_JD_JBCD_SRC) based on the JOBCODE_TBL record:
    SELECT a.jobcode 
    , a.descr 
    , a.eff_status 
    , a.flsa_status 
    ,a.job_family 
    FROM ps_jobcode_tbl a 
    WHERE 1=1 
     AND A.setid='GLOBL' 
     AND a.effdt = ( 
    SELECT MAX(a_ed.effdt) 
      FROM ps_jobcode_tbl a_ed 
    WHERE a_ed.jobcode = a.jobcode 
     AND a_ed.effdt <= sysdate)

This ought to return both active and inactive jobcodes (I am not specifying this in the view).  However, when I click the prompt button, only active jobcodes are returned.  A SQL Trace shows the following SQL being fired:
    SELECT  /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ JOBCODE, DESCR, EFF_STATUS FROM PS_AVZ_JD_JBCD_SRC     WHERE       EFF_STATUS<>'I' ORDER BY JOBCODE

Where is the eff_status criteria coming from?  The prompt is on a non-key field if that matters...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, EFF_STATUS is a "special" field & the component processor automatically applies eff_status (and effdt) logic on prompts.  To get around this, I replaced the EFF_STATUS field with STATUS & my lookup works as I wanted it to.